# ServiceStack GetSession() reload (using jwt auth)

Tags: c#, servicestack

Hopefully a quick question..

I've found that when using jwt authentication ServiceStack's `GetSession()` method doesn't fully refresh the session when the optional parameter `reload == true`.

```
var session = GetSession(reload: true);
```

session is very sparsely populated with some basic dates and an id.

Is that expected behaviour?
I'd expect it to return a full session object with the UserAuth populated?

EDIT: Fixed typo in method name (capitalisation - been working with typescript too much recently)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `getSession()` function in ServiceStack.dll that's camelCase so I'll just assume you're referring to the `IRequest.GetSession()` extension method.

The key thing to remember about JWT Token's is that they are **stateless** where they wrap [minimal user info](http://docs.servicestack.net/jwt-authprovider#jwt-payload) inside an encapsulated token to keep the JWT payload small as it's typically resent with every request. You can change what info gets embedded in the JWT using the [CreatePayloadFilter](http://docs.servicestack.net/jwt-authprovider#modifying-the-payload). You can also identify if a UserSession was only partially populated from a JWT with the `session.FromToken=true` property.

The other consequence of JWT's being stateless is that there is no state stored on the server anywhere, e.g. with typical [Cookie-based Sessions](http://docs.servicestack.net/sessions) the cookie contains a sessionId which refers to a UserSession that's persisted in the registered `ICacheClient` and calling `req.GetSession(reload:true)` will fetch the latest version of the UserSession from the cache. Since there is typically no UserSession persisted when using JWT's, there is no UserSession persisted in the cache that can be retrieved so ServiceStack returns an **Empty UnAuthenticated Session** (e.g. `session.IsAuthenticated=false`).

Instead if you want full information about the user you should fetch it directly from the Auth Repository using the `session.UserAuthId`, e.g:

```
var session = SessionAs<AuthUserSession>();
IUserAuth user = AuthRepository.GetUserAuth(session.UserAuthId);
```

If you need to do this frequently for information that's not encapsulated in the JWT Token by default you may want to consider using [CreatePayloadFilter](http://docs.servicestack.net/jwt-authprovider#modifying-the-payload) to embed this information in the JWT Token so you can avoid the I/O call to retrieve the User Information from the backend data store.

Comment: Yes, IRequest.GetSession(), apologies for any confusion

Comment: If I call GetSession() with reload = false (default) I get the full session details.  But if I use reload = true I don't.  So I understand what you are saying about the session being stateless but I get a session when I call GetSession() with no parameter....

Comment: @Drammy Mentioned in my answer, because `reload:true` returns the session loaded from the Cache, which for JWT doesn't exist. i.e. JWT's cant reload their sessions from the cache, to fetch the latest user info you need to access the AuthRepository directly.

Comment: ok, ta, so where does the session come from in this scenario when reload = false?

Comment: @Drammy from the session encapsulated in the JWT Token that when validated is attached to the current `IRequest`.